# How to deal with circular imports in tastypie

Tags: python, django, circular-dependency, tastypie

I'm currently developing a django-tastypie web app.
I've two django models :

```
class Student(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class Course(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
```

And from that, I've two Tastypie resources in two different files.
But here comes my problem. I want to be able to filter student from course, and course from student :

```
from website.api.course import CourseResource

class StudentResource(ModelResource):
  course = fields.ForeignKey(CourseResource, "course")

  class Meta:
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    resource_name = "student"
    filtering = { "course" : ALL }
```

and

```
from website.api.student import StudentResource

class CourseResource(ModelResource):
  student = fields.ForeignKey(StudentResource, "student")

  class Meta:
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    resource_name = "course"
    filtering = { "student" : ALL }
```

But of course, I got a circular import issue. How could I solve that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to import the other resource in each module. Try using a string as the argument instead.

```
class StudentResource(ModelResource):
    course = fields.ForeignKey('website.api.course.CourseResource', "course")

class CourseResource(ModelResource):
    student = fields.ForeignKey('website.api.student.StudentResource', "student")
```